# Is there a possibility to enable CSS3 features for internet explorer users?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, css

I'm using CSS 3 features like "rounded corner" or "shadow box". 
IMHO These are fantastic features for people like me with no graphics knowledge. But, i've noticed, IE 7-8 not support CSS 3.

So i'm asking you: is there a way to "enable" some features maybe with some javascript functions to include in my html file ?
Thank you!

Comment: Is there a relationship between HTML 5 and CSS 3 such that one implies the other?  I'm asking because the title says HTML 5, but the question is about CSS 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ie7-js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) fixes certain CSS issues.  I don't think the ones you named are included, but they might be in the future.

Comment: Hm. I didn't know about ie9.js

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [HTML5 enabling script](http://remysharp.com/2009/01/07/html5-enabling-script/), jQuery [dropshadows](http://code.google.com/p/dropshadow/downloads/detail?name=jquery.dropshadow.js&can=2&q=) and [corners](http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/).

Also, you might want to read a [good article](http://www.bioneural.net/2008/02/13/corners-gradients-and-shadows-with-jquery/) on making dropshadows, curvy corners & gradients using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot enable them, but you can detect them and mimic them using a good shot of JavaScript. [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) can be used to detect HTML5 and CSS3 features so that you can control the behaviour better. You can also use [jQuery Corner](http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/) and [jQuery Text-Shadow](http://www.hintzmann.dk/testcenter/js/jquery/textshadow/) plugins to progressively enhance the browsers not supporting them.

Note that HTML5 and CSS3 are **not** coupled to each other.

Comment: Modernizr specifically DOES NOT add features. Only detects them. From their own website: "Modernizr does not add missing functionality to browsers; instead, it detects native availability of features and offers you a way to maintain a fine level of control over your site regardless of a browser’s capabilities."

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is probably [Chrome Frame](http://www.google.com/chromeframe), but you have to convince your users to install it.

Comment: He asked about "javascript functions to include".  That's a far cry from a half megabyte .exe.

Comment: I was going to suggest that option too but am glad you did first! :)

Comment: I didn't say it was a great idea, just one option :p

Comment: Technically, he said "maybe with some javascript", implying that there's some flexibility there... :)

Comment: It's a little harsh to make anyone using less than IE9 install ChromeFrame... that said, it's definitely been my solution for "supporting" IE6 on a site or two (with the client's permission, of course).